# Software Update slows to crawl when upgrading linux-firmware

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, firmware

I have a laptop which over the years I have upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 20.04.  I tend to run Software Updater within minutes of receiving notification.  Usually this process takes about 5 minutes.  Today it took at least 45 minutes.  When updating `linux-firmware`, the process took at least 60 seconds to execute each of dozens of instances of older kernel versions and displayed messages like this:

```
modinfo: ERROR: could not get modinfo from 'crc32': No such file or directory
E: amd64-microcode: unsupported kernel version!
```

1. Can anyone explain what these messages mean?
2. Is there any workaround for this that will enable Software Updated to complete more quickly?

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit laptop? You may have had 14.04 32-bit installed on the laptop. The new Ubuntu releases are only 64-bit, although you can get 32-bit variants still from other distros. The 'amd-64' code refers to 64-bit architecture. It's telling you that your computer doesn't support that kernel possibly due to not having a 64-bit computer. But I may be wrong about that.

Comment: remove older kernels.

Comment: This is definitely a 64-bit computer, as confirmed by Settings/About/OS Type.